# Clickhouse active record datetime precision issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, clickhouse

I have gems clickhouse 0.1.10, clickhouse-activerecord 0.5.14, pg 1.4.6 and rails 7.0.4.3. ClickHouse server version 23.4.2.11, postgresql server 15.3.
My clickhouse table ddl:

```sql
create table default.tests
(
    id         UUID default generateUUIDv4(),
    created_at DateTime64(6)
)
engine = MergeTree PARTITION BY toMonth(created_at) ORDER BY (id, created_at);
```

My model is Test. When i create record like:

```rb
Test.create
```

this produces sql query:

```sql
INSERT INTO tests (created_at) VALUES ('2023-06-10 08:41:57')
```

As you can see there is no precision (microseconds).
I can define rails time db format like this:

```rb
Time::DATE_FORMATS[:db] = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%6N'
```

then if i create record this will produce correct result:

```sql
INSERT INTO tests (created_at) VALUES ('2023-06-10 08:41:57.123123')
```

But this broke my PostgreSQL models sql queries! For example if i have model PgTest and if i create record like this:

```rb
PgTest.create
```

this will produce incorrect precision sql query in my postgresql database (duplicate precision):

```sql
INSERT INTO pg_tests (created_at) VALUES ('2023-06-10 08:41:57.123123.123123')
```

Setting Time db format in callback around_create - not an option for me.

Comment: https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Aarchan937%2Fclickhouse%20DateTime64&type=code

looks like clickhouse 0.1.10 doesn't support DateTime64

try another gem

https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Ashlima%2Fclick_house%20DateTime64&type=code

Comment: click_house gem cool too, but i can't use this gem with clickhouse-activerecord

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was fixed in 0.5.15 version, last 0.6.0. For rails 7.1+ you need use branch `rails_7`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm created issue on https://github.com/PNixx/clickhouse-activerecord/issues/95
Gem clickhouse-activerecord <= 0.5.15 not add precision correctly with rails 7 for insert queries. This will be fixed in next gem's versions. So i'm just waiting this.